# Cordova jar in android

Tags: android, cordova, jar, version

What is the latest version of cordova for android. 
Please specify the link for jar file.
I referred here https://cordova.apache.org/ there is no jar file.

Comment: As you seem to be migrating an old project created with cordova 2.x to cordova 5, I suggest you create a new project using the --copy-from option of the "cordova create" command to import your existing html/js/... files and then add all the plugins you may need. I don't think trying to just paste new jar in place of old one is any good idea...

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
cordova platform version android
```

to check your actual android version.

1. If you want to update your cordova cli run `sudo npm update -g cordova`.
2. If you want to update your android platform only run `cordova platform update android`.

**Latest version of *cordova* is 5.1.1**

**Latest version of *android* is 4.0.2**

**Latest version of *ios* is 3.8.0**

You'll never find a `.jar` file for download on [cordova.apache.org](http://cordova.apache.org)

---

**Edited because of the comments below**

As it seems not to be clear which is the current working directory i'll describe this also.

1. `cordova create testProject com.example.com testProject`
2. `cd testProject`
3. `cordova platform add android / ios etc...`
4. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-pluginName`
5. `cordova build`

**The working directroy** which is needed for `cordova platform version android` **is reached in Step 2**.

Comment: I have installed cordova new version in ubuntu . How can I get its jar file now?

Comment: which `.jar` file are you talking about? There is a file called `cordova.js` which will handle your java <-> javascript/plugin connections.

Comment: There is one previous project which has cordova2.9.0.jar file so after installing new cordova 5.1.1 how can i rebuild the project to newer version of cordova?

Comment: move into your project directory with `cd` and (like i described above) run `cordova platform update android` via terminal.

Comment: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project. this error i got

Comment: Look onto my edit. Make sure you selected the right folder. If you still get this error, set up a new project with your needed plugins (i think you got a broken file inside your project). **First update cordova** and after you finished, you copy your `index.html` etc. in your new project.

Comment: from previous project should I remove the cordova2.9.0.jar file??